# Вывод чисел неверного диапазона в 2D массиве

Tags: c#

Мне нужен диапазон для создания массива [-10.51; 10.53], но мне выводит только числа которые <0. Подскажите, где я ошибся.

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

double[,] elems = new double[n, m];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine($"2D массив:");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    elems[i, j] = rnd.NextDouble() * 10.53 - 10.51;
                    elems[i, j] = Math.Round(elems[i, j], 2);
                    Console.Write($"{elems[i, j],4:f2} ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

Comment: Если от случайного числа, не превышающего 10.53, отнять 10,51, то очень редко получится что-то больше 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
elems[i, j] = rnd.NextDouble() * (10.53 + 10.51) - 10.51;
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думал что написание диапазона работает по-другому.